# Why do we have to repeat the fields in DoExpressCheckoutPayment while they were already set in SetExpressCheckout?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Why do we have to repeat the fields like `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0` or `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0` or `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC` or even `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` in **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** if we already set them in **SetExpressCheckout**? Shouldn't they be stored in the session that we've created in the first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEC simply prepares the system for a checkout and gives you a token.  Much could change between the SEC and the DECP call, so it's left up to DECP to finalize everything.

For example, with SEC you might pass a shipping address, but then during checkout the buyer changes it to one of their PayPal addresses.  Then when you call GetExpressCheckoutDetails you'd get back this address, so then the system wouldn't know which one you wanted to actually include with the order.  It would use whatever you pass into DECP.

Same with tax information, shipping, etc. which of course adjusts the final amount, too.  Maybe you don't have any address during SEC so you have to wait for GECD to get an address and calculate shipping and tax based on that.  Then the values for those parameters and the total would be different between SEC and DECP.

Those are just a couple of examples, but again, there are lots of things that could change between SEC and DECP depending on your application, so you just need to make sure that whatever you want to be included in the final payment details is included in DECP.

Comment: But what you describe sounds as optional anyway. What if I do not care about shipping details (I simply digital goods) or do not count any tax info? It should be as simple as confirming the payment from my side with the token and payer id only. Optionally I should be able to provide additional details if I so desire. It's terribly confusing at the moment.

Comment: That's just the way Express Checkout is designed.  No transaction is actually made until DECP is called, and whatever details are in that request are what get passed to PayPal's system.  Is it really that confusing to create the same request twice?  You could pretty much copy/paste your SEC if nothing is changing, and just change the METHOD, of course.